# Exposed Rcpp defined C++ function crashes R session, code snippets working before. Function exposition wrong?

Tags: r, memory, crash, statistics, rcpp

I have C++ code executed in Rcpp where I define a few functions that are then called in an exposed function using the `// [[Rcpp::export]]` tag. The code compiles fine but executing the exposed function returns in a fatal crash of my R session leading to immediate termination.

What mystifies me is that the code executed fine yesterday when I ran it up to the line `VectorXd z = y_luet - kroneckerProduct(X_luet.transpose(), MatrixXd::Identity(p, p)) * r;` and returning the vector `z`. Now, neither that nor the full code as displayed below work.

I have also done my homework of testing all functions individually, checking they are correct by exposing them to R before using the same technique and checking them against their slower R counterparts, obtaining numerically identical results (at greater speed).

I am wondering whether I am just using the 'define a few functions and then use them in a bigger function' approach is not appropriate as soon as the tasks become a little bigger?

The data themselves are moderate by Eigen's standards, dat is a matrix with 200 rows and 2 columns, everything else is low-dimensional, with the maximum of (row, column) not exceeding 12, i.e. the second-largest matrix is 12 by 1.

I am using Rtools and Rcpp all of the most recent vintage.

The code implements a simple iterated generalised least squares estimator, as is common in Statistics/Econometrics.

### Edit

Here is some sample data in R format that should get a minimal working example:

```
params <- .963
G <- matrix(c(1,0),nrow = 2)
G_perp <- matrix(c(0,1),nrow = 2)
mat_Lambda_lu <- matrix(0.95,nrow=1)
dat <- matrix(c(0,0,0,-0.79642284,-1.36694331,-1.18267593,-1.48827199,0.12549353,3.03343410,7.36256542,0,0,0,0.11282054,0.24798861,0.32448004,-0.27283699,-1.2462477,-0.0104694,3.21067339), nrow = 10, ncol = 2)
k<-3
no_ur <- 1
maxiter <- 100 #or something small for conserving memory
mini <- TRUE
```

The above should be executed in an R environment for it work. Please let me know if it doesn't work or if there are issues.

Here is the code:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/src/MatrixFunctions/MatrixPower.h>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/src/KroneckerProduct/KroneckerTensorProduct.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace Eigen;

//using Eigen::Map;                       // 'maps' rather than copies
//using Eigen::MatrixXd;                  // variable size matrix, double precision
//using Eigen::VectorXd;                  // variable size vector, double precision

MatrixXd makeXluet(MatrixXd dat, int k, int p, int T) {
  MatrixXd X_luet(p*k, T - k);
  for (int i = k; i > 0; i--)
  {
    X_luet.block((k-i)*p,0,p,T-k) = dat.block(i - 1, 0, T - k, p).transpose();
  }
  return X_luet;
}
MatrixXd makeRLuTilde(MatrixXd Rlu, MatrixXd LambdaLu, int k, int p, int q) {
  MatrixXd RLuTilde(p*k, q);
  MatrixPower<MatrixXd> Apow(LambdaLu);
  for (int i = k; i > 0; i--) {
    RLuTilde.block((k - i)*p, 0, p, q) = Rlu * Apow(i-1);
  }
  return RLuTilde;
}
VectorXd GLSEstimateFast(MatrixXd Xluet, MatrixXd Sigma_u, MatrixXd R, VectorXd z, int T, int k) {
  return (R.transpose() * kroneckerProduct(Xluet * Xluet.transpose(), Sigma_u.inverse()) * R).inverse() * R.transpose() * kroneckerProduct(Xluet, Sigma_u.inverse()) * z;
}
MatrixXd ResMaker(MatrixXd Xluet, MatrixXd Yluet, VectorXd beta, const int k, const int p) {
  Map<MatrixXd> A(beta.data(), p, k*p);
  return Yluet - A * Xluet;
}
double GLSCriterion(MatrixXd res, MatrixXd Sigma_u, const int k, const int p, const int T) {
  MatrixXd Lp = Sigma_u.inverse().llt().matrixL().transpose();
  MatrixXd v = Lp * res;
  Map<VectorXd> v2(v.data(), v.size());
  return (1 / static_cast<double>(T)) * v2.transpose() * v2;
}
MatrixXd CovEstFast(MatrixXd res, const int T) {
  return (1 / static_cast<double>(T)) * res * res.transpose();
}
double likeli_h(MatrixXd CovEstHat, const int T) {
  return (-0.5)*static_cast<double>(T) * log(CovEstHat.determinant());
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double restricted_iterated_ml_cpp(Map<VectorXd> params, Map<MatrixXd> G, Map<MatrixXd> G_perp, Map<MatrixXd> mat_Lambda_lu, Map<MatrixXd> dat, const int k, const int no_ur, const int maxiter, bool mini) {
  const int p = dat.cols();
  const int T = dat.rows();
  int p2 = static_cast<int>(pow(p, 2));
  int iter = 0;
  MatrixXd X_luet = makeXluet(dat, k, p, T);
  MatrixXd Y_luet = dat.bottomRows(T-k).transpose();
  Map<MatrixXd> D(params.data(), p - no_ur, no_ur);
  MatrixXd R_lu = G + G_perp * D;
  MatrixXd R_lu_tilde = makeRLuTilde(R_lu, mat_Lambda_lu, k, p, no_ur);
  MatrixXd C = kroneckerProduct(R_lu_tilde.transpose(), MatrixXd::Identity(T - k, T - k));
  MatrixXd C1 = C.topLeftCorner(no_ur*p, no_ur*p);
  MatrixXd C2 = C.block(0, no_ur*p, no_ur*p, C.cols() - (no_ur*p));
  MatrixPower<MatrixXd> Llupow(mat_Lambda_lu);
  MatrixXd mat_cee = R_lu * Llupow(k);
  Map<VectorXd> cee(mat_cee.data(), mat_cee.size());
  MatrixXd R(no_ur*p + k * p2 - (no_ur * p), k*p2 - (no_ur * p));
  R << static_cast<double>(-1) *    C1.inverse()*C2,
       MatrixXd::Identity(k*p2-no_ur*p, k*p2 - (no_ur * p));
  VectorXd r(k * p2);
  r <<  C1.inverse() * cee,
       MatrixXd::Zero(k * p2 - (no_ur * p), 1);
  Map<VectorXd> y_luet(Y_luet.data(), Y_luet.size());
  VectorXd z = y_luet - kroneckerProduct(X_luet.transpose(), MatrixXd::Identity(p, p)) * r;
  MatrixXd Sigma_u = MatrixXd::Identity(p, p);
  VectorXd gamma = GLSEstimateFast(X_luet, Sigma_u, R, z, T, k);
  VectorXd beta = R * gamma + r;
  MatrixXd res = ResMaker(X_luet, Y_luet, beta, k, p);
  double crit_old = GLSCriterion(res, Sigma_u, k, p, T);
  double crit_new = crit_old;
  do
  {
    crit_old = crit_new;
    Sigma_u = CovEstFast(res, T);
    gamma = GLSEstimateFast(X_luet, Sigma_u, R, z, T, k);
    beta = R * gamma + r;
    res = ResMaker(X_luet, Y_luet, beta, k, p);
    crit_new = GLSCriterion(res, Sigma_u, k, p, T);
    iter++;
  } while ((iter<maxiter) && (crit_old-crit_new>0.001));
  double ll = likeli_h(Sigma_u, T);
  if (mini) {
    ll = static_cast<double>(-1)*ll;
  }
  return ll;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some (random) sample data, such that others can (try to) reproduce the crash. Try to run R from the command line instead of some GUI. This way you might get useful information from the error message produced.

Comment: I was hoping it was an obvious mistake that is easy to spot but yes @RalfStubner I shall produce some sample data.

Comment: We generally recommend a [mcve -- minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  I agree that a minimal example is best, I was a bit time-pressured. Since my simulation routines are all written in R I would have to include quite a few lines of code here unless I can simply attach a few R scripts?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have added some extra lines with sample data in R. I understand that passing by reference could speed up the code considerably and will try that too but think this should not *crash* an R session. Again, many thanks for your help. Now that a MWE has been provided, can folks please upvote it by one so it's at least neutral, assuming your comments have been addressed? Vielen Dank...

Comment: I think this fails on _M_ side of things as it is not exactly _minimal_.  You want our help for free; maybe you will get better/more answers if you don't require us to analyze several dozen lines of code. (And for what it is worth I did not downvote, but I concur with the sentiment expressed in the downvote as this is currently not as good a question as it could be.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'd happily pay you a fair price. But jokes aside, how could I phrase it better? Sure, I can strip out all the auxiliary functions but then it would be a different problem, right? I have looked at the code very carefully and cannot find any obvious mistakes and have used a syntax-highlighting editor to make sure I am not wasting anyone's time. Just let me know what I should take out or change about my question and I'll happily defer.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel further to your comment about accepting free help here. I hope it may allay these concerns if you learn that I'm planning myself to make this available for free as this is part of a statistical methodology that I am releasing in the form of an article and an R package. So in the end, any help I get from this forum here shall be returned to the wider open source community.

Comment: You (still) misunderstand. I don't care if you get paid or not, or how.  I care about _my time_ and I am trying to explain to you, and failing, that you are more likely to get an answer to a well-prepared _short and precise question_ than to something long and meandering.  I too am an econometrician and I could probably work through your question but every day I get a number of _simpler and shorter_ tasks like this thrown at me, and _simpler and shorter_ tends to win.  Resources are finite and time is limited.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue on m machine. However, calling your function with the data you provided, the function returns `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks so much @RalfStubner that is helpful to know. I will debug the code in C++ first and then switch it back to Rcpp. Because with those inputs that returns a NaN for you, my R session crashes altogether.

Comment: I have now found the problem, which lay in kroneckerProduct which cannot evaluate matrix products as one of its arguments. So this is a bug in Eigen (their unsupported library) not Rcpp. I will write up an answer as a cautionary tale.